# Color of levelplot in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, levelplot

I have the following code. It produces a levelplot in which square values less than 0 should be colored in a red hue and squares with values greater than 0 in a blue hue. And then I would like squares with values of 0 to be colored white. However, nothing ends up being white. How can I fix this?

All three squares in that first column should be white.

```
library(lattice)

cc = colorRampPalette( c("red", "white","blue"))
trellis.par.set(regions=list(col=cc(20)))
x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
y = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
z = c(0,-2,-3,0,2,3,0,1,-1)
df = data.frame(x,y,z)
p <- levelplot(z~x*y, df,
               panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
                 })
print(p)
```

[image]

---

Update:
Here is a reproducible example that attempts to fix it, but still isn't quite right:
Here is a `dataframe` `df`:

```
    x y           z
1   1 1 -0.17457167
2   2 1  0.93407856
3   3 1  0.55129545
4   4 1  0.97388216
5   5 1 -1.00000000
6   6 1  0.52883410
7   7 1 -1.00000000
8   8 1  0.85112829
9   9 1 -1.00000000
10 10 1  1.00000000
11 11 1 -0.87714166
12 12 1  1.00000000
13 13 1 -0.95403260
14 14 1  1.00000000
15 15 1 -0.91600501
16 16 1  1.00000000
17 17 1 -1.00000000
18 18 1 -0.38800669
19 19 1 -0.52110322
20 20 1  0.00000000
21 21 1 -0.08211450
22 22 1  0.55390723
23 23 1  1.00000000
24 24 1 -0.04147514
25 25 1 -1.00000000
26 26 1 -0.39751358
27 27 1 -0.99550773
28 28 1  0.00000000
29 29 1  0.20737568
30 30 1  0.00000000
31 31 1  0.00000000
32 32 1  0.00000000
33 33 1 -0.26702883
```

And then here is the code:

```
cc = colorRampPalette( c("red", "white","blue"))
trellis.par.set(regions=list(col=cc(21)))
zrng <- range(z)       # what's the range of z
tol <- 1e-2            # what tolerance is necessary?
colorBreaks <- c(
  seq(zrng[1] - 0.01, 0 - tol, length.out = 11),
  seq(0 + tol,zrng[2] + 0.01,length.out = 10))  
p <- levelplot(z~x*y, df, 
               at = colorBreaks,
               panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
               })
print(p)
```

It produces this plot, which does not have a slot for the color white in the spectrum:
[image]

Comment: None of your colours as specified are white - `which(cc(20)=="#FFFFFF")` you need to do 2 separate colour ramps from red to white and then white to blue.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As thelatemail pointed out, `cc(20)` will never produce white (`"#FFFFFF"`).  You have to use an odd number for the middle value of the color ramp to be represented exactly (checkout `cc(3)` vs. `cc(4)`).

Now, you need to set the `at` argument for `levelplot` to set breakpoints for the colors.  The default is `at = pretty(z)`:

```
#[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

But you don't want 0 to be a breakpoint. You want it to have it's own color, and align with the middle of the color ramp.

You can achieve that by setting breakpoints as close to 0 as necessary (within some `tol`) to prevent any other values from mapping to white.  The rough idea is to leave a little spot for 0 by doing something like this `at = c(seq(-3.01, -0.00001, length.out = 11), seq(0.00001, 3.01, length.out = 11))` or using the similar method shown below.  Because the color ramp has an odd number of values, the sequence needs an even number of values.  (i.e. a color ramp of 3 colors can be divide by 2 breakpoints, but a color ramp of 4 values can be divided by 3 breakpoints)

```
trellis.par.set(regions=list(col=cc(21)))

# Define a sequence of breaks for the at argument to levelplot.
zrng <- range(z)       # what's the range of z
tol <- 1e-5            # what tolerance is necessary?
colorBreaks <- c(
  seq(zrng[1] - 0.01,  # adding a small buffer on end
      0 - tol,
      length.out = 11),
  seq(0 + tol,
      zrng[2] + 0.01,
      length.out = 11))  
      # note, I chose length.out = 11.
      # Don't do more than roughly ceiling((# of colors) / 2) 


p <- levelplot(z~x*y, df, 
               at = colorBreaks,
               panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
                 })
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so much. I tried this with a different data set, added some more padding, and now I get something like this: https://img42.com/vSz6n (it has the desired effect, but white is not landing at the 0 mark)

Comment: I should have mentioned. I'm still using cc(21) and it does produce #FFFFFF, and yet the color spectrum doesn't have white.

Comment: @CodeGuy I see.  Your argument to `at` needs to contain an even number of values, for 0 to fall in the middle.  Without an even number, there is no "middle."  So, instead of `length.out = 10` and `length.out = 11` make them both one or the other so that the sequence has an even number of entries.  If you have 4 colors in your spectrum, there are 3 (or 5 counting the extremes) breakpoints.  With an odd number, like 21, you need an even number of breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. So your example should be mofified as well?